# How to run concurrent Active Jobs in Spark Streaming and fair task scheduling among executors

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I am using Spark Streaming on Yarn, I am facing below issues.

Issue 1:

I am using spark streaming (1.6.1) on yarn, I always see active job count as 1 that means only 1 job is running at a time. I have used "`--conf spark. streaming. concurrentJobs=3`" parameter, but no luck I can see only 1 active job always.

[image]

Issue 2:

I have 50 Kafka partition and spark streaming creates 50 RDD partitions, but I can see 95% of task are allocated to only 1 executor rest of the executor mostly always have zero active task.

[image]

My Spark Submit command is as follows:

```
spark-submit \
--verbose \
--master yarn-cluster \
--num-executors 3  \
--executor-memory 7g \
--executor-cores 3 \
--conf spark.driver.memory=1024m  \
--conf spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=false \
--conf spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=3 \
--conf spark.streaming.concurrentJobs=3 \
--conf spark.speculation=true \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache=true \
--files kafka_jaas.conf#kafka_jaas.conf,user.headless.keytab#user.headless.keytab \
--driver-java-options "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./kafka_jaas.conf -Dhttp.proxyHost=PROXY_IP -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=PROXY_IP -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/user/spark-log4j/log4j-topic_name-driver.properties" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./kafka_jaas.conf -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/user/spark-log4j/log4j-topic_name-executor.properties" \
--class com.spark.demo.StreamProcessor /home/user/demo.jar /tmp/data/out 30 KAFKA_BROKER:6667 "groupid" topic_name
```

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the streaming tab ? Were batches getting queued up ? How fast is the input stream ?

Comment: @Hemanth Malla, Streaming jobs are not queued, they r getting processed in configured batch time. Regarding Issue 1: I can see more than 1 active jobs coming into picture when event messages load is more. So i guess I have understood pretty much about How active jobs get incremented. Issue 2:When I do re-partition I can see executors are doing more task as compared to without re-partition.

Answer (score -1):

--conf spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=3

Also why do you have max rate per partition so low ? this means it will process only 3 records per second per partition !!!!. So if microbatch interval is 30 seconds and say you have 3 partitions ,it ll processs 30*3*3 which is 270 records which seem pretty low.